# React JS : Yup & Formik Error Message showing multiple times on Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am using Yup and Formik for my Sign up Form.

I want to show an appropriate error based on my validation using YUP.

Below is my Code.

```js
import React from 'react';
 import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
 import * as Yup from "yup";
 
 
 function ValidationSchemaExample() {
     
     const SignupSchema = Yup.object().shape({
       name: Yup.string()
         .min(2, 'Too Short!')
         .max(70, 'Too Long!')
         .required('Required'),
     });


    function handleOnSubmit(values){
        console.log("Values : " , values)
    }

     return(
        
            <div>
              
              <Formik
                initialValues={{
                  name: '',
                  email: '',
                }}
                validationSchema={SignupSchema}
                validateOnChange={false}
                 validateOnBlur={false}
                onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}
              >
                {({ errors, touched }) => (
                  <Form id="submit_add_bom_form">
                    <Field name="name"  />
                     {errors.name && touched.name ? (
                      <div>{errors.name}</div>
                    ) : null}
                   
                   <ErrorMessage name="name" />

                  </Form>
                )}
              </Formik>

              <button form="submit_add_bom_form" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          
     )
 } 
 
 

 export default ValidationSchemaExample
```

**It shows me 2 times "Required" text instead of 1 time.**

When I click on submit button and if there is any error then it shows me twice instead of once.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this part:

```
// Error will be shown when there's an error for "name" and if the
// field is touched
{errors.name && touched.name ? (<div>{errors.name}</div>) : null}

<ErrorMessage name="name" />
```

Either remove that condition or `<ErrorMessage />` component